# How to create rectangle in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am struggling with a rectangle. I need to make a rectangle 30x30 moving from left to right. As a result I will have to calculate pixels from every slide. 
I'm thinking, do I have to use conv? Also I found that: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/23/sliding-windows-for-object-detection-with-python-and-opencv/
which seems exactly what I need but made in python - I am using Matlab. 
And that seems promissing: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBQI2wVSxSs
but not fully clear for me.
Any help would mean a lot to me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, your question looks like a homework question, so I'm going to link you to [the guidelines on those.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) In particular, you should try to implement something yourself and then ask about a specific problem with the implementation.

Comment: You need a `convolution` but not a `convolutional neural network`!!!!! a CNN is just a NN that uses a "simple" operation, convolution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need  to use convolutional neural networks. That website is mostly about deep neural networks using python. You can have your sliding windows in MATLAB as below:

```
I = imread('your_image'); % read your input image
if ndims(I) == 3 % convert your input image to Gray from RGB (if needed)
    I = rgb2gray(I);
end

winSize = 64; % size of your sliding window
step = 1; % steps by which sliding window moves (here is 1 pixel)
l = floor(winSize/2);
[R, C] = size(I);
for row = l:step:R-l+1
    for col = 1:step:C-l+1
        W = I(row-l+1:row+l-1, col-l+1:col+l-1); % This is your sliding window value
        % do your calculations on sliding window (W) here

    end
end
```

In every loop iteration you have your next sliding window and you can perform whatever calculations you want.